# Repo plugin for TeamCIty?

Tags: git, plugins, teamcity, repo

I have a manifest file that contains names of repos from which source has to be pulled in TeamCity? Is there an equivalent of repo plugin (Jenkins) in TeamCity? If no, do I need to create VCS root for each repo specified in the manifest? 
Also, I need to trigger the CI when any change is detected in the repo.

Comment: You could parameterize the VCS root and specify the group/repo/branch as parameters to a build configuration.

Comment: the build will pull from all the repo's mentioned in manifest. How will the parameterization of the vcs help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you have to create a VCS root for each repository at least up to TeamCity 9. It might have been improved in TeamCity 10. You can also configure trigger on each Build Configuration to start build on VCS Root change. It is possible to store the Build Configuration in a source control, like Git. It explained in details [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control)